# is $\exp \in \operatorname{End}(\mathfrak {h})$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let G be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}=Lie(G)$ and  $\mathfrak{h}\subset \mathfrak{g}$ a subalgebra.

I saw in some proof that if $t\in \Bbb R$ and $X\in \mathfrak{h}$ and $ad(tX)\subset \mathfrak {h}$ then $\exp(ad(tX))\subset \mathfrak {h}$

I don't see why it is the case, to my knowledge $exp\not \in \operatorname{End}(\mathfrak {h})$.

The proof was meant to show that $Ad(\exp(tX))\subset \mathfrak {h}$ using the identity $Ad\circ \exp = \exp \circ \,ad$.

Many thanks for any help/hint in the right direction.

Comment: Usually $\exp$ is $\mathfrak g\to G$. What sense does it even make to claim that $\exp(\cdots)\subset \mathfrak h$?

Comment: Exactly, that what I know. I preferred to ask in case there might be some other property of the exponential that I am missing

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169275/lie-groups-and-exponential-map).

Answer (score 2):

Pardon the simplistic language, as I am a physicist, so I'm not sure the street version of the structure would satisfy you.
The fundamental identity invoked is what many call [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma)
in deriving the CBH formula.

That is, for $t\in \Bbb R$ and for any $X,Y\in \mathfrak{h}$,
and $ad(tX)\subset \mathfrak {h}$ you have
$$\exp(ad(tX)) Y =Y+ ad(tX)Y+ \frac{1}{2!} ad(tX)ad(tX) Y+...= Y + [X,Y]+ \frac{1}{2!}[X,[X,Y]]+ ... \in \mathfrak {h}$$
since all commutators of the Lie sub algebra elements are in it.

You apply the identity $Ad\circ \exp = \exp \circ \,ad$ on the left-hand side.

I am more used to starting with the Ad(exp(*tX*)) being in the subagebra and differentiating w.r.t. *t* to go backwards.